# Mongodb aggregation json format by month result

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Hello I am working with the reporting api which will going to use in highcharts and I am new to mongodb.

Below is my aggregation query (suggest me modification) :

```
db.product_sold.aggregate({

    $group: {
        _id: { year: { $year: "$solddate" }, month: { $month: "$solddate" }, productid: "$productid" },
        totalQty: { $sum: "$qty" }
    }

})
```

Output:

```
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "year" : NumberInt(2019), 
        "month" : NumberInt(2), 
        "productid" : "11"
    }, 
    "totalQty" : 6.0
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "year" : NumberInt(2019), 
        "month" : NumberInt(2), 
        "productid" : "14"
    }, 
    "totalQty" : 7.0
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "year" : NumberInt(2019), 
        "month" : NumberInt(1), 
        "productid" : "13"
    }, 
    "totalQty" : 3.0
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "year" : NumberInt(2019), 
        "month" : NumberInt(2), 
        "productid" : "10"
    }, 
    "totalQty" : 6.0
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "year" : NumberInt(2018), 
        "month" : NumberInt(2), 
        "productid" : "12"
    }, 
    "totalQty" : 5.0
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "year" : NumberInt(2019), 
        "month" : NumberInt(2), 
        "productid" : "15"
    }, 
    "totalQty" : 8.0
}
// ----------------------------------------------
{ 
    "_id" : {
        "year" : NumberInt(2019), 
        "month" : NumberInt(1), 
        "productid" : "11"
    }, 
    "totalQty" : 2.0
}
// ----------------------------------------------
```

What I want in output is something like :

```
status: 200,
msg: "SUCCESS"
data: [{
    1:[
        {
            "productid": 11,
            "totalQty": 3
        },
        {
            "productid": 12,
            "totalQty": 27
        }
    ],

    2:[
        {
            "productid": 11,
            "totalQty": 64
        },
        {
            "productid": 12,
            "totalQty": 10
        }
    ]   
}]
```

For reference attaching the image of the collection

[image]

Is there any way to achieve it using aggregation or anything else or I will have to do it manually by code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can append below aggreagation stages to your current pipeline:

```
db.product_sold.aggregate([
    // your current $group stage
    {
        $group: {
            _id: "$_id.month",
            docs: { $push: { productid: "$_id.productid", totalQty: "$totalQty" } }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            k: { $toString: "$_id" },
            v: "$docs"
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {
            _id: null,
            data: { $push: "$$ROOT" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            data: { $arrayToObject: "$data" }
        }
    }
])
```

The idea here is that you can use [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) with `_id` set to `null` to get all the data into single document and then use [$arrayToObject](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayToObject/index.html) to get month number as key and all the aggregates for that month as value.

Comment: I will give it a try

Comment: @SagarVirpara that's because you're using MongoDB below 4.0, you can use `k: { $substr:["$_id", 0, -1 ]}` as a workaround instead of `k: { $toString: "$_id" }`

Comment: Okay.. what If I want to get given year's data like 2019 ?

Comment: I am using mongodb version 3.2 so I am also not able to use $arrayToObject.

Comment: @SagarVirpara any possibilities of upgrading your MongoDB ? I'm afraid it's the only way to dynamically generate your keys

Comment: Finally updated mongodb to v4 it took me 2 hours.. your solution working as expected..

Comment: Now I am looking for result yearly basis, like year inside all months data. i.e. data : root 2018 child all months, root 2019 child all months

Comment: @SagarVirpara please open another question, I will try to help you

Comment: I was working with the above query and now I realized that I need a array of data and you solution is giving me object..

Comment: You can wrap thata object with an array in your app logic - don't need to use Aggregation Framework for it

Comment: Okay. Now the thing is that I need to use this in sails js with waterline orm.. got stuck

Comment: are you aware about waterline ORM ?

Comment: @SagarVirpara, unfortunately no